# Is having raid0 zfs pool with copies=2 datasets equals to having raid1 zfs pool?

Tags: raid, zfs

I have a computer with 2 hdds, which I want to use for data storage.
Initially I wanted to create mirrored zfs pool, but not so much data needs to be stored so safely.
So, if I create zfs pool with raid0 vdev and set copies=2 on specific datasets (for example, on which I am going to store family photos or similar), will that be same as having two pools, one mirrored for more critical data, one raid0 for standard data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, [`copies=2` does not give you device redundancy](https://jrs-s.net/2016/05/02/zfs-copies-equals-n/)!**  Do not use `copies=2` instead of a mirror vdev!

If a device that is its own vdev (as in RAID 0) fails, you cannot import your pool.  All your data would be gone.

There is no benefit at all to using `copies=2` instead of a mirror vdev.  There are only downsides:

- Slower write performance due to double writes and fragmented seeks.
- `copies=2` doesn't even protect your data that well.  [Here](https://jrs-s.net/2016/05/09/testing-copies-equals-n-resiliency/) is an experiment that shows that if a random 0.1% of the disk is corrupted in a pool 85% full, files are still lost.

What should you do instead?  You should set up your disks in a mirror (RAID 1) and have a backup to a different pool somewhere else.  The backup would be for your extra important files like the family photos you mentioned.  [Never forget that RAID is not backup.](https://superuser.com/a/1457251/83694)

If your budget really is just two hard drives, I would create two individual pools made of the individual disks and `zfs send | zfs receive` the important files between the two.  This is a bit of a hassle, which is why I only suggest it if you have no other options.  It sure is safer than RAID 0 with `copies=2`.